# A greyed answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, down-votes

I recently came across [Solving the problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/380088/solving-the-problem).  Although the user who posted a completely off topic post about cooking, which garnered 6 down-votes in 5 seconds has removed it.  However, I noticed that the answer was sort of greyed, and only when my cursor went on it did it become normal.  Went back to grey condition when my cursor went away.  Why is this so?

Comment: The rapid downvotes may have been due to the Smoke Detector script/bot. It catches lots of obvious spam and downvotes automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is by design: answers with scores below -3 get grayed out, to indicated that they do not have the community's endorsement.